# Correct indexing of named vectors

Tags: r, indexing

This is a very quick and simple question that I am sure has been asked repreatedly on here. However after 45 minutes of searching I cannot answer the problem. Please link to whichever is the relevant question or delete it if needed.

I have the following:

```
>str(slope)
List of 55
$ : Named num [1:2] -0.00044 0.00311
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "y"
$ : Named num [1:2] 1.374 -0.0276
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "y"
$ : Named num [1:2] 3.704 -0.102
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "y"
$ : Named num [1:2] 9.275 -0.294
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "y"
$ : Named num [1:2] 15.76 -0.46
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "y"
$ : Named num [1:2] 16.27 -0.443
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "y"
$ : Named num [1:2] 25.973 -0.717
```

How do access all values of "y" e.g. if I want to plot them? I can access individual "y" values using:

```
> slope[[ c(1, 2) ]]
[1] 0.003111922
```

but not all of them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sapply(slope, `[`, 2)
```

Also try

```
foo <- do.call(rbind, slope)
foo[,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sapply` and `[[`:

```
sapply(slope, '[[', "y")
```

or maybe

```
sapply(slope, '[[', 2)
```

If it doesn't work, then provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and some data.